# How to use the sudo command

Tags: sudo

When I want to install a package with the `sudo` command I am asked to type in my password, but nothing shows up when I do.

Answer (score 4):

Just enter your password, nothing is reflected on the screen as you type.

Answer (score 2):

The password remains invisible as you type for security measures. hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

It's okay. Just type in the password and press enter and you're good